# Create span around text based on offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

We are trying to fit the content in div inside main div. But half of the line is being cut. How should we avoid this. How should we identify that line and create span around those words and move it slightly up or down.

We were trying with `offsetheight`, `offsetTop` etc as we do not want to use scroll bar. Any idea in jquery to handle this.

Code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejaswi_kandula/r5eZ7/)

Comment: Can you supply some code and a jsfiddle page so we can see what is going on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tejaswi_kandula/r5eZ7/

Comment: I'm confused what the purpose of wrapping a span around those words and moving them slightly up or down will accomplish - can you explain your ultimate goal for this?

Comment: Do you control the text length of what shows up in each p? if so, you shouldn't need to move that text - you can just limit the number of characters in each p tag so that you dont have text hidden.. just a thought

Comment: Actually iam trying to fit the text in div based on the height of div by using margin-top as i move the content up half of the line is getting cut so if i wrap the text with span and find offset i can either add or subtract the offset and fit in div part

Answer (score 0):

I am playing around with your code... I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to accomplish.. but check out the revisions I made and let me know if it gets you any closer to what you are trying to do.

I added in the functionality for the next and previous and also modified your surrounding box so there is no padding. You can tweak all this, but maybe this will prevent the need to try to move stuff around via jquery?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/r5eZ7/3/

```
 $(".next").click(function() {
    var visiblep = $(".content p:visible");
    if (visiblep.next().length == 0) 
    {
      $(".content p:first").show();
    }
    else
    {
      visiblep.next().show();
    }
    visiblep.hide();
  });
```